# How to obtain depth map from stereo camera?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, stereo, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to try a visual odometry algorithm with the KITTI dataset. However the KITTI dataset, in my case, has only sequences of pictures with the left and right camera. I don't have any cloud or depth information in the dataset. (Actually yes there is also velodyne data but i'm not interested in laser for now)

Therefore, I presume that from the left and right camera, I have to obtain the depth map (correct me if I'm mistaken) ?
How i can do that in ROS ? I saw that there is a node called *stereo_image_proc node*  who can deal with stereo but I only can obtain a disparity MAP and I didn't find any topic that publishes this depth map.

EDIT: I can have the disparity image or/and the pointCloud2

Can someone help me ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206665/how-to-obtain-depth-map-from-stereo-camera-?/) by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-04-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally was able to obtain the depth map from the disparity picture thank to the disparity_image_proc nodelet. It used an OpenCV function to project disparity into 3D space.

The main issue was the the fact that image_view and stereo_image_view nodes didn't work in my ROS indigo (https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues/117) and therefore I wasn't able to obtain a good depth map because i couldn't adjust the parameters properly in real time because I couldn't see the results directly.

Finally, I installed ROS Hydro and I could change the parameters directly with image_view. And now It works !

EDIT: by the way can you explain me how to run the script you provided ? I'm not able to make it work despite i followed the python tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) with karma: 93 on 2015-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sai Anirudh Kondaveeti](https://answers.ros.org/users/22508/sai-anirudh-kondaveeti/) on 2015-05-21**:
How did you change the parameters in real time?. thanks

**Comment by [lilouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/21904/lilouch/) on 2015-05-22**:
I followed this link: http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc/Tutorials/ChoosingGoodStereoParameters

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi lilouch,

there are some steps you have to do before obtaining the depth image or the pointcloud (what do you prefer?)

1. Publish the images as ROS topics: Write a node to do that, or use one already available. For instance [this one](https://github.com/srv/srv_tools/blob/indigo/bag_tools/scripts/bag_tools/image_sequence_publisher.py). You'll need two instances of this same node, one for the left camera and one for the right.
2. Run stereo_image_proc to rectify the images and calculate their disparity. This node calculates also the pointcloud. From the pointcloud you've already got the depth, but in case you need a depth image, read below:

As you may already know, depth can be calculated from disparity using *Z = fB/d*, where *f* is the focal lenght (px), *B* is the baseline (m) and *d* is the disparity (px). *Z* is depth in m. Both *f* and *B* are fixed terms, so your entire disparity image inverted (termwise), multiplied by a constant is your depth image.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2015-04-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1